# JWE and JWS, are they "stateless"?

Tags: encryption, jwt

Lately I have been reading some about JWT/JWS and JWE.. however.. one part I still dont get is that Im quite sure that I somewhere have read that they all should be "stateless", is this true?
My take on this would be that JWS and JWE would require a shared secret between the "acquirer" and the "issuer" to be able to decrypt the payload (and CEK and what not depending on JWS or JWE).
So my question is.. is JWS and JWE truly stateless? And if thats the case, then how come we dont need to store a secret between the "acquirer" and the "issuer"? Or is the kid used for fetching our secret from for instance a database to decrypt the payload and/or CEK?

**To clarify**,
Is there a shared secret between the issuer and the acquirer when using JWS and/or JWE to decrypt and encrypt the token? Is this secret stored in a database on the issuer to be able to decrypt the payload and/or the CEK or is the secret/key used to decrypt and encrypt shared some other way?

This question is based on the following article regarding JWT,JWS and JWE:
https://medium.facilelogin.com/jwt-jws-and-jwe-for-not-so-dummies-b63310d201a3

Answer (score 0):

You are right: Depending on your application, it may be stateful.
From my point of view, you could ditinguish two cases:

1. Your application issues JWE or receives JWS
2. Your application issues JWS or receives JWE

With the first use case, the JWS signature can be checked using the issuer public keys. These keys are (broadly speaking) shared with the parties by the issuer (this what [Google](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) and [other authorities](https://developer.okta.com/authentication-guide/tokens/validating-id-tokens#retrieve-the-json-web-key-set) do). Same goes when you want to encrypt a token (JWE) to that recipient: you will use its public key.

With the other use case, your application will need to have access on a key set with private keys. Those keys are necessarily stored somewhere (a DB, an environment variable...).

When shared keys are used (rarely used with 3rd parties), you may be in the use case #2 as both the issuer and the recipient have to manage the shared key.